# Withdrawal safety from scam?

Tags: remix, metamask, code, withdrawal

Thank you for taking your time to explain & help

Basically i'v run a bot (from scam...) on scammed remix environnement..
I'v several error when trying to withdrawal, one of them was that there was not enough Ether to make profit (so scam want me to add an 1 other  ETHER...)

Today I'v runned the same bot on an offcial remix, and don't see the error regarding the "add 1 more Ether" anymore when triying to withdrawal.

When metasmask open itself to see the amount of Ether + Gas fees to withdrawal, i have a warning who told me that Etherscan can't double check my contract, and so there is a potential risk to withdrawal.

From what i understood, it's at this time that the bullsh*t code will send the Ether to the scam wallet, right ?

Can some one confirme this information regarding the code :
https://pastes.io/raw/099rlawerm

My contract : 0xCa7f6a5900bC0976ce03b5AF94E34AA4f9370810
(you can see error each time i'v tryed to withdrawal from the scam remix environnement : revoked)

Today, my Ether is still on contract, i'v mooved my last amount of money out of metamask.. main goal is to bring back this 1  ETH to my wallet, but i'm affraid that if i confirm the withdrawall it will go straight to his pocket..?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing you could do. The contract you have deployed is a well known scam contract.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ismael.. I was confuse because without puting the code an on official remix, they don't allow to withdrawal so.. there is no sense !

Comment: SO, if i let the Ehter on contract it's lost for everybody ? If i withdrawall it's on his pocket ? I saw a lot of similar bot, but was transfer all the wallet straight to the scam wallet. Here it's differents, cause if i don't go to a real remix, it not let me withdraw...

Comment: There are slight variations on the contracts. I think this fits the second link. The scammer address is obfuscated inside `parseMemoryPool`. It cannot be changed for already deployed contracts. Anyone can start a withdraw but the funds will go to the scammer address.